# Как сделать рассчетный столбец с обращение к столбцу датафрейма через .at[][]?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть исходная таблица:

```
    Доходы      Расходы     Прибыль_убыток
18  3951.75     3694.90 
19  2367.36     2397.76 
20  5059.94     7034.75 
21  617238.27   730198.44   
22  543420.00   564063.24   
23  60242.50    61467.50    
24  300500.00   302302.72   
25  601225.00   601456.26   
26  601475.00   601397.61   
27  14728.73    14553.88    
28  15517.78    20861.63    
29  539160.00   538739.66   
30  87260.00    89390.04    
31  8.75        8.94    
32  5889.02     5035.57
```

Как провести данные расчеты с обращением к столбцам (Доходы - Расходы) с использованием .at:

```
profit_loss = sell_year.iloc[:]['Доходы'] - sell_year.iloc[:]['Расходы']
sell_year.iloc[:]['Прибыль_убыток'] = profit_loss
```

При запуске кода:

```
profit_loss = sell_year.at[:, 'Доходы'] - sell_year.at[:, 'Расходы']
sell_year.at[:, 'Прибыль_убыток'] = profit_loss
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
InvalidIndexError: slice(None, None, None)
```

Comment: Зачем вам здесь `at`? этот метод работает с единичным значением. К слову, `iloc` в данном случае тоже не нужен. Да и вспомогательная переменная ни к чему. `sell_year['Прибыль_убыток'] = sell_year['Доходы'] - sell_year['Расходы']`

Comment: что-то вы намудрили, ей-богу. просто вычтите из одного столбца другой. df["result"] = df["one"] - df["two"]

Comment: Если просто вычесть таким образом df["result"] = df["one"] - df["two"] вычисление произойдет, но я получу предупреждение. Вариант .iloc не приводит к каким-либо предупреждениям. За уточнение работы at, спасибо.